# URL routing in asp + c# webpages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to route url for my zip code project, i need to route my url like - `www.example.com/pincode/{country}/{state}/{district}/{area}/.`

Below line is working fine for me

```
//to show all countries eg. example.com/india/
routes.MapPageRoute("showcountries", "pincode/{country}/", "~/pincode/country.aspx");
```

But i'm getting not found error when i increase code or url. My global.ashx file's code given below

```
// To show all states list of mentioned country in url eg. example.com/india/maharashtra/
routes.MapPageRoute("showstates", "pincode/{country}/{state}/", "~/pincode/state.aspx"); 

// show all districts from url eg. example.com/india/maharashtra/pune/
routes.MapPageRoute("showdistricts", "pincode/{country}/{state}/{district}/", "~/pincode/district.aspx"); 

routes.MapPageRoute("showdivisionpin", "{country}/{state}/{district}/{division}/", "~/pincode/division.aspx");
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Shouldn't the last one also start from `pincode/{country}/{st..` just like the others? Is `division` supposed to be _literally_ `/division` or a parameter `{division}`?

Comment: #degant my error is The parameterized query '(@querystatename nvarchar(4000),@querydivisionname nvarchar(5))s' expects the parameter '@querystatename', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the working of this line

routes.MapPageRoute("showdivisionpin", "{country}/{state}/{district}/{division}/", "~/pincode/division.aspx");

Can you plz check with giving like this

routes.MapPageRoute("showdivisionpin", "division{country}/{state}/{district}/{division}/", "~/pincode/division.aspx");